# TkinterVideo - I want to make it larger than what it appears

Tags: python, tkinter, video, resize

I create a tkintervideo element to play a video I created using moviepy. The images I insert into the video are 400x400. However, when I ask the tkintervideo to display the moviepy mp4 file, it appears smaller than what it actually is. Here is my code that creates & displays the video:

```
# Create a video from the wordcloud images
        if chosen_mwordclouds.get() and num_wordclouds > 1:

            # Check if a wordcloud label already exists
            if hasattr(hashtag_frame, 'wordcloud_label'):
                # Destroy the previous label widget
                hashtag_frame.wordcloud_label.destroy()

            video_path = 'wordcloud_video.mp4'  # Set the video file path


            # Create a list of image paths for the wordclouds
            image_paths = ['wordcloud_' + str(x + 1) + '.png' for x in range(num_wordclouds)]

            # Create a list of images from the image paths (multiplied by 36 to make the video longer)
            images = 36*[cv2.imread(image_path) for image_path in image_paths]

            print(len(images))

            # Create a video clip from the list of images
            clip = ImageSequenceClip(images, fps=1)

            # Save the video clip as a video file
            clip.write_videofile(video_path)

            # Check if a video label already exists
            if hasattr(hashtag_frame, 'video_player'):
                # Destroy the previous label widget
                hashtag_frame.video_player.destroy()

            video_player = TkinterVideo(hashtag_frame, width=400, height=400)
            video_player.load("wordcloud_video.mp4")
            video_player.pack()
            video_player.play()

            def loopVideo(event):
                video_player.play()

            video_player.bind('<<Ended>>', loopVideo)


    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please enter a hashtag')
```

And here is the size of the video in the GUI:

[image]

And here is the size of one of the individual images (not a tkintervideo, just a standard tkinter label):

[image]

How can I make the video larger? Keep in mind that the code that creates the mp4 file and creates the tkintervideo element is within a 'generateWordclouds' script, not the 'main' one.

I have tried to make the tkintervideo larger on the GUI, but it just won't change. The video just stays the same size despite the actual images being inserted into the video are larger than the video that is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of `tkVideoPlayer.TkinterVideo`.  Based on the code of the function `_set_frame_size()`:

```py
def _set_frame_size(self, event=None):
    """ sets frame size to avoid unexpected resizing """

    self._video_info["framesize"] = (self._container.streams.video[0].width, self._container.streams.video[0].height)

    self.current_imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new("RGBA", self._video_info["framesize"], (255, 0, 0, 0)))
    self.config(width=150, height=100, image=self.current_imgtk)
```

The above function (which will be called before playing the video) has set the `width` and `height` to 150 and 100 which make the final video size to `150x100`.

To work around it, you can bind `<<Loaded>>` virtual event and set the required size inside the event callback:

```py
video_player.bind("<<Loaded>>", lambda e: e.widget.config(width=400, height=400))
```